# Pass API Gateway custom domain tags to lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way of passing custom domain name tags to a lambda? I'd like to store some properties in the tags and read them in the lambda implementing the API, ideally passing them into the lambda event or context.

Could it be done by coding HTTP request headers into the API definition? If so I don't know how to get the custom domain name tag data from here.